# Display Via Category links Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, sql, laravel, routes

i have a side-nav with 4 buttons:

**Computers

Laptops

Mobile

Tablet**

What i want is a way to route my views so i could get the posts that are only on that category.

**CategoryContoller**

```
  public function show(Category $category)
    {
      $posts = Category::findOrFail($category)->posts()->get();
    return view('pages.computer',compact('category'))->with('posts',$posts);
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('{category}',[
             'uses' => 'CatController@showComputer',
             'as' => 'pages.computer']);
```

Going this way if i put mywebsite/Computer i get all the posts that are in Computer category, same if i go with mywebsite/Mobile.
***So the query is working.***
Now how can i:

**{{ route('') }}**

my Views so i can get each category to show up via the sidenav links.

Answer (score 1):

You can create  `@foreach` loop in your **view** to render all your categories for example:

```
<ul>

  @foreach($categories as $category)

    <li><a href="categories/{{ $category->name }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></li>

  @endforeach

</ul>
```

## Edit :

to get all the **categories** in your **links** in the view you have to get them first in the Your **controller** and then pass them with the view:

first you have to create a route :

```
Route::get('/',[
             'uses' => 'CatController@index',
             'as' => 'pages.index']);
```

in your existing **index** method :

```
public function index {
   $categories = Category::all();
   return view('pages.index',compact('categories'));
}
```

Comment: Simple way, but how can i choose the category name without manually typing mywebsite/Computers

Comment: Yes i know then you can loop through them as i showed you at the top of my answer. is that what you want to achieve ?

Comment: What you say gives me all the categories!! What i want is this: i have my route set to Route::get('{category} '), etc... Now what i am looking for is a way to use blade route to get a link to use the above route, and the category field to be Computers or Mobile or any other Word i want.

Comment: This route will give you a collection of links like `example.com/category1` and `example.com/category2` and so on. and sorry if i don't get your point

Comment: So to get the category1 route with {{ route('pages.computer')}} how should i pass that?

Comment: you can pass the category as [Eddy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4464871/eddythedove) has mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something similar.

```
<a href="{{ route('pages.computer', ['category' => $category->name]) }}">
    {{ $category->name }}
</a>
```

Just replace `->name`by whatever column you are using in your url.

Comment: that looks like a good way to go !! will try it after i get home , meanwhile my issue is that i cant figure out how to get the Computer category name to appear on my URI without me typing it manually!! kinda confused for some reason .
If i go {{ route('pages.computer') }} i get missing one URI argument {category}.

Comment: you pass the category in the curly braces the way I did.

Answer (score 0):

If your route is something like that

```
Route::get('/categories/{slug}', 'CategoryController@menuCats');
```

You can use the URL of this route as below in your blade templates.

```
<span><a href="{{url('categories/'.$category->slug)}}"></a></span>
```